# Django + JQuery - Iterate over table rows updating each row with json data

Tags: jquery, django

I have table rows that look like this

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr id="labels" data-index="{{ forloop.counter }}"> </tr>  
{% endfor %}
```

I have this json data:

```
"labels": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C ",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F",
    "G",
    "H",
    "I",
    "J",
    "K",
    "L",
    "M",
    "N",
    "O",
    "P",
    "Q",
    "R",
    "S",
    "T",
    "U",
    "V",
    "W",
    "X",
    "Y",
    "Z"
],
```

Im trying to iterate over the table rows and the json data at the same time, so that I can assign each table row its label.

```
jQuery.each(labels, function() {
newlabel = this;
document.querySelectorAll('#labels').forEach(function (element, index) {
element.innerHTML = newlabel;
});
})},
```

But with this all the rows are populated with the letter Z, instead of being A-Z in alphabetical order.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is the solution:

```
var iLabel = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('#labels').forEach(function (element, index) {
element.innerHTML = iLabel < labels.length ?
labels[iLabel] :
'undefined';
iLabel++;
});
```