# Django + JQuery - Append bars to table rows

Tags: jquery, django

[image]

I have table rows that look like this:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <tr class="rows"></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and bars that look like this:

```
{% for item in items2 %}
    <div class='bar bars'></div>
{% endfor %}
```

now I want to attach each bar to it's row, the first bar to the first row and so on...

So I found out that the below does not work because .innerHtml is not an attribute of a jquery object, so I tried using .html but that doesnt work either.

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    bars = document.querySelectorAll('.bars').forEach(function (element, index) {
    var iBars = 0;
    document.querySelectorAll('.rows').forEach(function (element, index) {
    element.innerHTML = iBars < bars.length ?
    bars[iBars] :
    '';
    iBars++;
    })
    })
});
```

I get this:

[image]

---

I also tried using fragments:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.bars').forEach(function (element, index) {
    allbars = $(this);
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment.appendChild(allbars);
    rows = document.querySelectorAll('.rows').forEach(function (element, index) {
    rows.appendChild(fragment);
    })
});
```

with this I get: TypeError: Argument 1 ('node') to Node.appendChild must be an instance of Node

---

So I tried assigning an ID to each row and bar individually first:

```
<div class="rows" id="row{{ forloop.counter }}" ></div>
<div class='bars' id="bar{{ forloop.counter }}" ></div>

var thisrows = $("#row1");
console.log(thisrows);
var thisbars = $("#bar1");
console.log(thisbars);
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild(thisbars);
$(thisrows).appendChild(fragment);
```

but still: TypeError: Argument 1 ('node') to Node.appendChild must be an instance of Node

---

Thank you for any help

Comment: Why do this in JS? It makes much more sense to amend the template

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't know what you mean with "amend the template", but the length and position of the bars change based on some other stuff, therefore I want them to stay as dynamic as possible.

Comment: Don't assign same id to many items. ID should be unique. If you want to give each element in for loop same identifier use `class` instead.

Comment: Changing their properties is fine in your JS, I'm referring to their physical location in the document which is what you're currently trying to change. It makes far more sense to put them where they need to be in the template, instead of hacking them around in JS on the client after the template has been rendered

Comment: ... so nest them?

Answer (score 1):

Prepare your data from the backend code like creating a dictionary that combines items and items2 under one key. it's faster than Django renderer.

Comment: basically I have 2 qs: 1 holds the data for the bars (name, start and finish date) and the other one holds the data for the table (amount of rows and cells in dates).
If I combine the 2, I get the same amount of bars as rows, which I don't want.

Comment: Use the data as the main key, and if it has a bar, add the bar to the same key, like this you will have bar related to its data, so when you for loop on the data, you check if it has a bar to print it.

Comment: what I usually do in this case, I add a div for the bar and use the property `width` out of 100% to fill it with the background color, so you have to calculate the percentage for each bar and give it directly to the template.

Comment: the width and the horizontal position works already, Im just struggling with the vertical position aka how to place them inside the rows

Comment: Share with me the view, and I will help you with it.

Comment: Ive done everything with js. The view passes the qs to the template and nothing else

Comment: ok, if you want to this using the js, you have to create a unique id for each row, for example "row-24/11/2019" which is the "row-"+ the date for the row, then add data for the bar like data="24/11/2019" which is the date for the bar.
then looping over the class bars, and appending the bar to the right row. please let me know if you need extended code for this.

Comment: I did something similar without using id's for the x - axis here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692122/django-jquery-iterate-over-table-rows-updating-each-row-with-json-data

I just took all the labels and all the rows and assigned the first label to the first row and so on, which is what I am trying to do with the y - axis too.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to what you are trying to do, each row has a bar

```
{% for row in rows %}
    <tr class="rows" id="row{{ forloop.counter }}">
      <div class='bar' id="bar{{ forloop.counter }}"></div>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey, basically I have 2 qs: 1 holds the data for the bars (name, start and finish date) and the other one holds the data for the table (amount of rows and cells in dates). If I combine the 2, I get the same amount of bars as rows, which I don't want.

Comment: @User9023 when you say combine you mean you want this `rows = [ { bars: [ ... ]  }, .... ]`. That way each row can have `n` number of bars?