# Django + JQuery - Interactive Gantt Chart

Tags: javascript, django

Im working on an interactive gantt chart with django and jquery.

I build the table like this:

```
<div class="gantt">
<div class="gantt-labels">
    {% for item in items2 %}
    <tr>
    <div class="gantt-labels" id="labels"> </div> 
    </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="gantt_timeline">        
<div class="table gantt_table" id="myTable">
<thead>
<div class="gantt-tr time-bar"> 
    {% for item in items2 %}
    <div class="gantt-td chart-values">{{ item.y|date:"D" }}</div>
    {% endfor %}                                
    </div>
</thead>
<tbody>      
{% include "datamodel3.html" %}
    {% for item in items2 %}
    <div class="tr gantt-tr rows" id="row{{ forloop.counter }}" >
        {% for item in items2 %}
        <div class="td gantt-td"> </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The queryset "items2" holds the data for the table (amount of rows and cells in dates)

Example:

row1 01/01/2012

row2 02/01/2012

...

row31 31/01/2012

---

datamodel3.html

Here are the bars:

```
{% for item in items3 %}
<div class='bar resizable bars' style="pointer-events:visible;" id="bar{{ forloop.counter }}" data-duration="{{ item.start|date:'D' }}-{{ item.end|date:'D' }}">
<div class='resizers'>
    <div class='resizer top-left'></div>
    <div class='resizer top-right'></div>
    <div class='resizer bottom-left'></div>
    <div class='resizer bottom-right'></div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The queryset "items3" holds the data for the bars (name, start- and finish-date)

Example:

bar1 01/01/2012 10/01/2012

bar2 08/01/2012 14/01/2012

---

I use this to make the bars draggable:

```
(function() {
    $(".bar").draggable({
    containment: "parent"
    });
})();
```

---

I use this to make the bars resizable:

https://codepen.io/ZeroX-DG/pen/vjdoYe

---

I use this to schedule them:

https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/ZEzerNB

---

I use this to assign a label to each row:

```
var iLabel = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('#labels').forEach(function (element, index) {
element.innerHTML = iLabel < labels.length ?
labels[iLabel] :
'';
iLabel++;
})
```

---

So far, the bars have the right length (start and finish date), are draggable and resizable.

The only thing for now is to append each bar to its row (first bar to first row and so on....)

I tried different ways, but ended up assigning each row and bar an ID and attaching them to one another:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
newfunction();
});

function newfunction(){
    var thisrows = $("#row1");
    var thisbars = $("#bar1");
    /* var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); fragment.appendChild(thisbars); */
$(thisrows).html(thisbars);
}
```

When I try to use fragments, I get: TypeError: Argument 1 ('node') to Node.appendChild must be an instance of Node.

Now, instead of hard-coding every id, I tried to do something like this:

```
function newfunction(){
var n = 0;
var e = 0;
$(".rows").each(function(){
var thisrows = $(this).attr("id") + n;
n++;
});
$(".bars").each(function(){
var thisbars = $(this).attr("id") + e;
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment.appendChild(thisbars);
e++;
});
$(thisrows).appendChild(fragment);
};
```

Which doesnt work, even without using fragments. Any suggestions?

---

Also, I want to save the new position and length of the bar when I move/resize it.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Thank you in advance

Here is my first post about this with an image of the table:

[Django + JQuery - Append bars to table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747926/django-jquery-append-bars-to-table-rows)

Comment: You make your life unnecessary very difficult. Please consider using [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) for creating a Gannt chart.

Comment: Yes, in fact Im using a pre-build gantt chart now.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure I get the entire context but I think there some errors in the code, here is my attempt to resolve the script:

**The only thing for now is to append each bar to its row (first bar to first row and so on....)**

```
function newfunction(){
  const bars = $(".bars");
  $(".rows").each(function(index){
    $(this).html(bars[index]);
  });
};
```

To save the new position and length of the bar when I move/resize it, boils down to having an object with unique id for the bar `{ [bar id]: { position: ... , size: .... }, ...}` or straight up array of bars `[{ id: ..., size: ... } , ...]` where you can easily switch positions. You update the object in the observer/listener.

Comment: Hey, please see my first post about this and why this doesnt work